# Is it possible to save the database password as hashed?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configuration

In the `app/etc/local.xml` file, when adding the database configuration, is it possible to have the password hashed or encrypted instead of having it in plain text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - maybe ... but.

1. Hashing: means one-one encryption. What means, that you can't regain the password. Without password you can't  login. You can maybe hack mysql to use the hash instead of the password, but then you didn't solve your security issue, because the hash works as password.
2. Encrpytion: You can encrypt the password in the `local.xml` and reimplement `\Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getConnection()` in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php:110` to decrypt the password and use it. The problem here is, if you are able to decrypt the password, everyone is, who can read the file. If you ask me, pay an administrator a lot of money who knows his job and don't invest in this. It is snake oil.

Comment: "It is snake oil" — Best part of the answer! :) If they have access to your server, you have bigger problems.